# How to print wchar_t variables in C

Tags: c, char, wchar-t, wchar

I am debugging some old C code written in our company. The function is something like this --

```
uint32
ExecuteCommand(wchar_t *dnsName,           // IN
                                wchar_t *dnsUser,   // IN
                                PNameValue *nameValues, // OUT
                                size_t *valuesSize)     // OUT
{
   ....
```

To debug this, I need to examine the values of dnsUser and dnsName being passed into this function. I tried the below options --

```
    Util_Log(L"Printing the userName %S", dnsUser);
    Util_Log(L"Printing the userName ", dnsUser);
    Util_Log(L"Printing the userName %ls", dnsUser);
    Util_Log(L"Printing the userName %lS",dnsUser);
```

Util_Log is a proprietary logging API used in our company. However, none of the above is working and the userName is getting printed in some garbled form in the generated logs. I tried using printf and wprintf but that didnt print anything in the logs--

```
  printf("Printing the userName %S",userName);
  wprintf("Printing the userName %lS  %S", userName);
```

Just to add: Below is the signature of SimCfg_Log API.

```
void
Util_Log(const wchar_t *fmt,  // IN
         ...)                   // IN
```

What is the correct way to print the wchar_t arguments in the method ? Also, any idea why using printf and wprintf is not printing anything in the logs?

Comment: Did you check with your debugger what is in `dnsUser`?

Comment: Yes when I checked in debugger, dnsUser is some valid name like John, David etc and not garbled character

Answer (score 2):

My psychic powers suggest this is all you need to do:

```
Util_Log(L"Printing the userName %s", dnsUser);
```

My psychic powers are aided by two hints:

The first hint being that the the first param to Util_Log is a wide-char (`L""`) string.  Hence the format specifier, `%s,` would also get interpreted as a wide-char string.

The the second hint is that it's he only format specifier you didn't mention as having already tried. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but it didnt work, FYI the signature of the method is this,-void
Util_Log(const wchar_t *fmt,  // IN
         ...)     , so I was thinking it should work

Comment: That's the problem with psychic powers, they sometimes fail you.  Obviously, anyone on your team would suggest you consult with the owner of the `Util_Log` API within your company or inspect the source code yourself.  Are you saying you have no access to either and must link with a pre-compiled lib?  Otherwise, your last resort is to do what Mathieu suggest below.  `swprintf` to a temp buffer.  Then pass that to your logging function.

Answer (score 1):

You could not use the formatting options of your internal function and rely on [swprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wprintf):

```
#define SIZE 256
wchar_t buffer[SIZE];
swprintf(buffer, SIZE, L"Printing the userName %s",userName);

Util_Log(buffer);
```

Comment: Since the OP indicated my suggestion did not work, I'm upvoting this answer. My advice to OP is to be careful with string lengths (use snprintf) and when `userName` itself has a `%s` escape sequence. I'd hate for your logging statement to become a security hole.